# Counting points within polygon and extracting the data

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, extract, count

I have been given a CSV file which contains the Longitude and Latitude data points for a number of mobiles that run our own internal app. The data includes the unique `"ID"` for the device plus a date & time stamp for each ping received.

I have been asked if I can extract the data to show only the mobiles within a specific area. I'm new to this so based on research I think I need to create polygon covering the area we are interested in and then work out which points are within that polygon.

I have downloaded and installed some software called QGIS which seems like its capable of doing what I need. I have imported the CSV file which looks correct.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to go about getting the info i need. Ultimately I wanted to extract the points I'm interested in and then load that into kepler.gl to have a graphical view of the movements over a period of a week so I need to retain the unique `"ID"` and date / time stamp but for only the points within my polygon.

Comment: QGIS is capable of time-visualization. Check the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/index.html) and [official training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/index.html).

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do - however, try `Menu Vector / Analysis Tools / Count points in polygon`. Otherwise, use QGIS expressions (with field calculator or select by expression) to define a filter based on `overlay_within` (to get the points in the polygon), combined with the condition for the timestamp.

Comment: @Babel, thanks for the info, that sounds like what i need to do. However i'm a step behind unfortunatley. I am struggaling to work out how to create the polygon. Is this something i do within QGIS or do i create it elsewhere and import it? Thanks.

Comment: Create a new lyer (I recommend: Geopackage) of polygon type, then draw the polygons. See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "specific area". If it's a municipality/state/country, you should be able to download boundaries from public repositories. If it's another kind of area, like a zone around a specific point, you can create a buffer. Or, you also can draw it by hand in QGIS.

Comment: OK, so i moving forward. I have a layer showing all counties in the UK, i have create a new layer based on the county i am interested in. I followed @Babel instructions by using menu item Vector/Analysis Tool/Count Points in Polygon.
I selected my Polygon and the points file which is my CSV file. Click Run. I get an error re spatial index but it quickly finished. However i get no points number.. everything suggests it has worked but there is no result?

Comment: Do your points show on the map canvas? You could help us adding a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, both teh points layer and area layer are enabled and you can see them both on the canvas

Comment: As a new user to GIS SE, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, which isn't well-suited for broad introductory topics. We're a problem-solving site, not a tutorial one, better suited to answering a Question about the error message you seem to have ignored. While it's not necessary to spend a semester learning about GIS to use QGIS, overlay operations are not likely to be the first exercise. Generally speaking, it would be faster to identify indexed points within a polygon than to test if each point is contained by a specific polygon.

Comment: OK, Thanks All for your help. I get the felling this is beyond my skills as a Newbe to GIS. I don’t particularly want to learn GIS as this is a short term one off project. I have budget to get external help so if anyone wants to offer a short training session to just get the data i need or point me in the direction of someone / services that can help I’m all ears. Once again, thank you to everyone that provided help, I fully appreciate Stack Exchange is not that type of service. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

> Not exactly sure what you want to do - however, try Menu Vector / Analysis Tools / Count points in polygon. Otherwise, use QGIS expressions (with field calculator or select by expression) to define a filter based on overlay_within (to get the points in the polygon), combined with the condition for the timestamp.   [Babel, 2021]

In QGIS, or other GIS software,

1. Import .csv data
2. create a layer
3. create the desired polygon
4. using Clip tool or Count Points in Polygon tool, extract/count the points.

I would personally draw the polygon and use the clip tool to create a clipped dataset with the desired area of concern, and the clip tool won't drop the attribute/table data. If it needs to be exported into .csv you can do that using QGIS.

If you are new to QGIS, here are some helpful link on the subject:

- [QGIS User Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/)
- [How to open data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=csv)
- [How to create layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html)
- [Page on general Vector Processing (including Clip tool)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html?highlight=clip)